# How To Remove the Symbol from the string

Tags: c#, .net, json, string, string-formatting

i am having the string like this

```
string value="{\"email\":\"test@example.com\",\"password\":\"passworddata\"}"
```

i want to remove this symbol("\")
and i want string as like this

```
"{"email":"gg.com","password":"ff"}"
```

Comment: It will be. What you have there are _escaped characters_. Specifically escaped quotes. When you print your string the slash won't be there.

Comment: I hope \ are not there in the output. Its a escape character without it you can't have "

Comment: @GOPI: If you tag this as both vb and C# you will get useless answers.  fix your tags.

Comment: i had try this but it will show error string value = registerDetails.Replace('\',"");

Comment: Rephrase your question.

Comment: first how do you have a string with so many double quotes in it and no concatenation operator ?

Comment: So please specify accordingly, we don't have so much time to keep making guesses.

Comment: why is it making problem for you , the backslashes are automatically escaped i think ? u shouldn't need to do anything ?

Comment: @tariq yes u correct the backslashes automatically remove...Thanks for your help

Comment: added it as an answer u can accept it, will help others too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslashes are automatically escaped u shouldn't need to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like it could be JSON; although, you're representing it as an embedded C# string.

Let's say it was this in c#

```
    string value = "{\\\"email\\\":\\\"xxx@example.com\\\",\\\"password\\\":\\\"passworddata\\\"}";
```

that on console output looked like:

```
{\"email\":\"xxx@example.com\",\"password\":\"passworddata\"}
```

You could use regex to strip the escapes:

```
var val = Regex.Replace(value, "\\\\([^\\\\])", "$1");
```

so that on output you would have:

```
{"email":"xxx@example.com","password":"passworddata"}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind, you could try this code:

```
string result = value.Replace("\\", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you:

```
public string Formatter(string MainText, char CharToRemove)
{
    string result = MainText;
    foreach (char c in result)
    {
        if(c == CharToRemove)
        result = result.Remove(result.IndexOf(c), 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
string value = "{\"email\":\"xxx@gamil.com\",\"password\":\"passworddata\"}";            
value="\"" + value.Replace("\\", "") + "\"";
```

Output:

```
"{"email":"gg.com","password":"passworddata"}"
```

Answer (score -3):

Place the edit cursor (I-bar) behind each `\` character and press <kbd>Bksp</kbd>

As per `King King`'s request:
An aternative method would be to place the I-bar in *front* of the `\` and press <kbd>Del</kbd>

Comment: are you in a bad mood :D ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: my answer addresses the terms stated in the question.  As the code appears to be C# in nature, and those backslashes are exactly what is needed to achieve the OP's desired result at runtime, I can only assume they want it to look like that at design time.

Comment: I suggest to add more on the use of `Delete` key